# The System cannot find the path specified - Apache Spark-Windows 10

Tags: windows, apache-spark, environment-variables

I have installed java,scala,python,spark on windows 10
Placed winutils.exe file is in C:\Hadoop
Below are the variables I have set up

User Variables

```
HADOOP_HOME  C:\Hadoop
SCALA_HOME   C:\Program Files (x86)\scala
JAVA_HOME    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
PYTHON_HOME   C:\Users\rajes\PycharmProjects\2021\venv\Scripts
SPARK_HOME   C:\Spark1\spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7
```

User Variables - PATH Variable Has below values

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin
C:\Users\rajes\PycharmProjects\2021\venv\Scripts
C:\Spark1\spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7\bin
```

SYSTEM VARIABLES

```
HADOOP_HOME C:\Hadoop
SCALA_HOME   C:\Program Files (x86)\scala
JAVA_HOME   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
PYTHON_HOME  C:\Users\rajes\PycharmProjects\2021\venv\Scripts
SPARK_HOME  C:\Spark1\spark-3.0.3-bin-hadoop2.7
```

SYSTEM Variables - PATH Variable Has below values

```
%HADOOP_HOME%\bin
%SCALA_HOME%bin
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin
%PYTHON_HOME%
%SPARK_HOME%\bin
```

While i am trying to run spark-shell from command prompt "The system cannot find path specified is displayed"
Attached Screenshot .

[Screenshot showing installations and Error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwhcE.png)

Comment: Spark doesn't support Java 17, last I checked, and you shouldn't make a Python venv be your system Python. Plus, you should try using the Hadoop that came with Spark rather than set it up separately

Comment: Thank you for your help . The issue is resolved now . Uninstalled all the software and have installed the below versions


C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
C:\jdk\bin\java.exe

C:\Python27\python.exe

C:\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7

C:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe

Pycharm Tool : pycharm-community-2021.2.2

I have created java and jdk outside the Program Files Folder .
I have created java and placed the JRE files 
I have created jdk  and placed the jdk files

This is resolved the issue and was able to connect to Apache spark in Windows 10